# After installing the Quartz 3.0.0 package System.IO.FileLoadException: ''Newtonsoft.Json, Version=8.0.0.0 error

Tags: .net, json.net, nuget, nuget-package, quartz

After installing the Quartz 3.0.0 package
System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file ''Newtonsoft.Json, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or its assembly code or one of its dependencies. The manifest definition of the deployed embedded code does not match the embedded code reference. (HRESULT returned exception: 0x80131040)'

I got the error. How can I solve this? I also tried different 3.0.7 versions of Quartz and it didn't work.
When I remove the quartz package, there is no problem.